# React Native Expo Video av-expo

Tags: react-native

I'm trying to do this in react native using `av-expo.`

1. When the button is pressed, a video component is rendered in fullscreen mode,  portrait orientation.
2. When exiting from fullscreen, the video component is hidden.

I'm not able to:

- show it in fullscreen mode
- detect the exiting event from the fullscreen mode.

```js
 function showVideo(){
    <Video
      source={{ uri:'http://d23dyxeqlo5psv.cloudfront.net/big_buck_bunny.mp4' }}
      resizeMode="cover"
      useNativeControls
      style={{ width: 300, height: 300 }}/>
    }

  export default function App(){
    const[state,setState]=useState(0)
    return(
      <View>
        {state ? showVideo() : null}
        <Button onPress={=>(setState(1)}/>
        <View>
      )
  }
```

Would anyone please help me?

Answer (score 2):

Since you use `av-expo`; there are [FullScreen](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/video/#the-following-methods-are-available-on-the) APIs for you.

The following methods are available on the component's ref:

- videoRef.presentFullscreenPlayer(); use this to present Video in the fullscreen mode.
- videoRef.dismissFullscreenPlayer()

and use `onPlaybackStatusUpdate`, a function to be called regularly with the `onFullscreenUpdate`, a function to be called when the state of the native iOS fullscreen view changes (controlled via the `presentFullscreenPlayer()` and `dismissFullscreenPlayer()` methods on the Video's ref.

```js
export default class App extends React. Component{
  _videoRef;

  showVideoInFullscreen = async () => {
    // PlaybackStatus https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/av/
    const status = await this._videoRef.presentFullscreenPlayer();
    console.log(status)
  }

  dismissVideoFromFullscreen = async () => {
    const status = await this._videoRef.dismissFullscreenPlayer();
    console.log(status);
  }

  onFullscreenUpdate = ({fullscreenUpdate, status}) => {
    console.log(fullscreenUpdate, status)
    switch (fullscreenUpdate) {
      case Video.FULLSCREEN_UPDATE_PLAYER_WILL_PRESENT: 
        console.log(' the fullscreen player is about to present');
        break;
      case Video.FULLSCREEN_UPDATE_PLAYER_DID_PRESENT: 
        console.log('the fullscreen player just finished presenting');
        break;
      case Video.FULLSCREEN_UPDATE_PLAYER_WILL_DISMISS: 
        console.log('the fullscreen player is about to dismiss');
        break;
      case Video.FULLSCREEN_UPDATE_PLAYER_DID_DISMISS: 
        console.log('the fullscreen player just finished dismissing');
    }
  }

  render () {
   return (
       <View style={styles.container}>
           <Video
               ref={(ref) => (this._videoRef = ref)}
               source={{ uri: 'http://d23dyxeqlo5psv.cloudfront.net/big_buck_bunny.mp4' }}
               resizeMode="cover"
               useNativeControls
               onFullscreenUpdate={this.onFullscreenUpdate}
               style={{ width: 300, height: 300 }}
           />
           <Button
               title={'show video'}
               onPress={() => {
                   this.showVideoInFullscreen();
               }}
           />
       </View>
   );
  }
}
```

output

```
the fullscreen player is about to present
the fullscreen player just finished presenting
the fullscreen player is about to dismiss
the fullscreen player just finished dismissing
```

[image]